# OpenCV 4.4.0 error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor' , 14 other erros module cv2

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, keras

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi_gray = cv2.resize(roi_gray,(48,48),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    # rect,face,image = face_detector(frame)
        if np.sum([roi_gray])!=0:
            roi = roi_gray.astype('float')/255.0
            roi = img_to_array(roi)
            roi = np.expand_dims(roi,axis=0)
        # make a prediction on the ROI, then lookup the class
            preds = classifier.predict(roi)[0]
            label=class_labels[preds.argmax()]
            label_position = (x,y)
            cv2.putText(frame,label,label_position,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,2,(0,255,0),3)
        else:
            cv2.putText(frame,'No Face Found',(20,60),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,2,(0,255,0),3)
    cv2.imshow('Emotion Detector',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

1. **ERROR**
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-6lylwdcz\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdczo.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I30vx.png)

Comment: Most probably, you can't get `frame` from the `cap.read()` check whether `ret` returns `True`.

Comment: As @Ahx mentioned ret must be True, also for `cap.isOpened()`. If both of them are True, then try `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==False:
        continue
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
```

Add this if condition in your code.
If "ret" always return "False" then change "cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)" as "cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)" and try again

Answer (score -1):

All you have to only change this line

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

to

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to insert the USB2.0 device into a certain port of the computer, and then compile the program.